# Differentiability of $x^2$

Tags: limits, derivatives, continuity

I tried checking differentiability of $x^{2}$ and on its right hand side, rate of change of $y$
with respect to $x$ was $0^{+}$ and on left hand side was $0^-$.

What does this $0$ imply? And how can we say it is differentiable at $x = 0$ since they are not same?

Also can anyone please help me comparing it with $|x|$ since its right hand derivate is $1$ and left hand derivative is $-1$. So, does it imply that if I increase value of $x$ by $1$, $y$ increases by $1$ on right hand side?

Here is the

$$f'(0^+)=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}\frac{h^{2}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^{+}}h=0^{+}$$

$$f'(0^-)=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^{-}}\frac{h^{2}}{h}=0^{-}$$

[image: Derivative]

Comment: $\lim_{h\to 0^+}h=\lim_{h\to 0^-}h=0$, plain and simple, not $0^+$ or $0^-$. $0^+$ and $0^-$ are not *numbers* (except in `computer science`, sometimes...): those are *symbols* that are applicable in $\lim$ notation to specify how the limit is taken.

Comment: Well, I don't understand the downvote. On other hand. If the laterals limit there exists and they are equals $\ell$ so the limit there exists and it is $\ell$ for functions from real to real.

Comment: The downvote may be because it is highly frowned upon in the MSE community to post a question with images, when one can type the question using MathJax (which then makes the question searchable and avoids any problems with bad handwriting - not saying the latter is the problem *here*...)

Comment: It should be a number greater than 0? And not exactly 0

Comment: I have added my "grain of sand" to the OP's post. On the other hand, I agree with Stinking Bishop's comment about notation, though I've seen it in other contexts like here https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/convergencefourierseries.aspx#:~:text=The%20theorem%20for%20integration%20of,integral%20of%20f(x)%20.

Answer (score -1):

This is the problem with the ‘handwave’ definition of a limit that is taught in first year calculus courses.

Supposing $f(y)=z$, then for example $\lim_{x \rightarrow y} f(x) = z$ is shorthand for writing: for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ such that $x \in (y-\delta, y+\delta)$ we have $f(x) \in (z-\epsilon, z+\epsilon)$. In other words, as $x$ gets close to $y$ from any direction, then $f(x)$ gets close to $z$.

On the other hand, $\lim_{x \rightarrow y^+} f(x) = z$ is shorthand for writing: for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $x$ such that $x \in (y, y+\delta)$ we have $f(x) \in (z-\epsilon, z+\epsilon)$. In other words, as $x$ gets close to $y$ from the right, then $f(x)$ gets close to $z$.

The meaning of $\lim_{x \rightarrow y^-} f(x) = z$ is similar to $\lim_{x \rightarrow y^+} f(x) = z$. It is then clear that $\lim_{x \rightarrow y^-} f(x) = z$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow y^+} f(x) = z$ together is equivalent to $\lim_{x \rightarrow y} f(x) = z$.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. The asker is claiming that $x^2$ is not differentiable because the left- and right-hand limits are different. This is a valid argument; it's the premise that's false. Bringing up the epsilon-delta definition doesn't seem relevant to me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Sambo this is what I am asking.

Comment: Well what does  $lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} f(x)=z$ precisely mean if not using an epsilon-delta definition? Every other way is "handwavy" and technically just shorthand. Notice the formal definition never mentions $0^+$ or $0^-$. The confusion comes from the shorthand notation, when looked at formally the confusion goes away.